# Nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type + getProfiler()Lcom/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OProfiler; @4: areturn

Tags: java, compiler-errors, orientdb

My code is:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(GlobalProperties.orientDB_IP, GlobalProperties.orientDB_user, GlobalProperties.orientDB_pwd);
```

But I'm getting the below issue when I try to hit the call from API:

> Exception Details:   Location:
>       com/orientechnologies/orient/core/Orient.getProfiler()Lcom/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OProfiler;
>   @4: areturn   Reason:
>       Type 'com/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OAbstractProfiler' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to
>   'com/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OProfiler' (from method
>   signature)   Current Frame:
>       bci: @4
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'com/orientechnologies/orient/core/Orient' }
>       stack: { 'com/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OAbstractProfiler' }   Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 2ab4 0003 b0 ] with root cause java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type Exception Details:   Location:
>       com/orientechnologies/orient/core/Orient.getProfiler()Lcom/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OProfiler;
>   @4: areturn   Reason:
>       Type 'com/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OAbstractProfiler' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to
>   'com/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OProfiler' (from method
>   signature)   Current Frame:
>       bci: @4
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'com/orientechnologies/orient/core/Orient' }
>       stack: { 'com/orientechnologies/common/profiler/OAbstractProfiler' }   Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 2ab4 0003 b0
>
> ```
>     at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.<clinit>(ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.java:50)
>     at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.ORecordSerializerFactory.<init>(ORecordSerializerFactory.java:48)
> ```

What can I do?

Comment: Hello, did you find anything on this issue?

Comment: Well, for me it turned out that the library orientdb-commons was overriding something. I removed it from my dependencies and it works now like a charm.

Comment: @PaulRey Thanks for your response I too removed the dependency and it worked fine.

Comment: Ok I'll write it as answer then

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me it turned out that the library orientdb-commons was overriding something. I removed it from my dependencies and it works now like a charm.